# REST API in djangorest framwork

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, backend

I am making API in Django rest and I am not sure what to do with groupID. I have just 1 model - countries. I have assigned request and response.

Request for POST is :

```
{"name": "Czech Republic","countryCode": "CZ"}
```

Response is:

```
{ "name": "Czech Republic","countryCode": "CZ","id": 123,"createdAt": "2022-08-21T11:49:39.239Z", "groupId": 123 }
```

And I am supposed to create an API for that. I am not sure what to do with groups in model.

```
class Countries(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   countryCode = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   groupId = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):return self.name
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9vPQ.png)

Comment: Please show your code that handles this POST request, and also - what's your actual question? The `id` field is an autoincrementing primary key that is automatically added by `django.db.models.Model` - you can disable this behavior if you want, but if your question is that you only want specific fields in your response, that's up to your code.

Comment: for POST request I use standart django ListCreateAPIView. But I was wondering, how should I write the groupId field, so it would look like on picture. Because in POST request, I am not putting any number there

Comment: What is `groupId` supposed to represent? Should it be exactly the same as `id`? It sounds like the `groupId` is automatically generated and your schema either should have it be auto-generated, or you create it when the country is added to the db.